# Does SSRS need to be installed locally?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

In the past I've just always accessed SSRS through a browser. Does it need to be installed on the local machine accessing the SSRS browser page, or do you just need to have the link to the SSRS web location in order to run reports and access report builder there?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: has it stopped working that way for you ?

Comment: No, I guess I just wanted to be sure as I've never installed SQL Server on a machine personally and will soon be heading a few hours away to give someone a tutorial on SSRS. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding something - end users have accessed it without the install before, but they also didn't try using report builder on the site.

Comment: Nothing needs to installed on your machine in order to use the browser.